# Woocommerce REST API - Add custom routes

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop and I'm using the Woocommerce REST API to list products etc. on another site and it works fine. There are some functionality that I'm missing though, and I'm wondering if it is possible to extend the API with custom calls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to this by reading the source code for Woocommerce.

First I had to create a class that extends WC_API_Resource and add my routes in the register_routes method of this class. Then I had to make sure that Woocommerce adds this class to the API by adding the class to the class-array in the woocommerce_api_classes filter.

Comment: Just curiosity.
 
**how to extend?**
**1) by creating plugin or adding file on the wc?**
**2) if i extend by creating plugin how i will got WC files to extend library?**

Comment: You can do it in a plugin. As long as you use the filter woocommerce_api_classes, which is called by WC, you should be fine.

Comment: Hey @Nocklas I've made a plugin called custom-endpoints, now its its class file I've done it so it extends WC_API_Resource but upon activating it claims it cannot find the resource. Any help?