# Is it possible to add a new API endpoint that uses WooCommerce's authorization?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to add an API endpoint in my WordPress plugin that will write to the database, etc. I want it to be triggered by a remote system that will call this new API.

However, I'd like to use the built-in WooCommerce REST authentication, the auth set up here:

[image]

(And no, those credentials don't work, anymore).

Is there a way to do this? To add a custom HTTP endpoint that will use the auth from WooCommerce and then run some arbitrary code that I want to run?

Or is there a way to add a hook on an existing WooCommerce API endpoint to run before that endpoint executes? I just need a way to use the existing WooCommerce REST API auth to trigger some updates I need to run in my plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a route under the Woocommerce endpoint to use this key/secret authentication system.

Here's a working example:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wc', '/test', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ]);
});

function my_awesome_func(WP_REST_Request $request)
{

    if (is_user_logged_in() && (int)wp_get_current_user()->ID === 123) {
        //your stuff only for legged in user 123
        return new WP_REST_Response('ok', 200);
    }

    return new WP_Error('unauthorized', __('You shall not pass'), [ 'status' => 401 ]); //can also use WP_REST_Response

 }
```

This will:

- add a new GET route under the "wc" endpoint (woocommerce one), so `https://example.com/wp-json/wc/test`
- you then use "HTTP Basic auth" to pass your key and secret as per [Woocommerce documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication-over-https)
- the results of `is_user_logged_in()` and `wp_get_current_user()` will depend on the correct combination of key/secret. If correct, a the associated user will be "authentified" as for Wordpress.
- if correct combination you'll get `[true, WP_user_object]`, if incorrect key `[false, Empty_user_object]`.
- If correct key and incorrect secret, a 401 will be thrown (not the one in my example, another 401 by woocommerce. `my_awesome_func()` is not reached in this case. I believe it's like wp-login, custom error message when correct login (key), nice ^^')

You then need to secure your route by your rules:

- Checking if user is logged in like `if(!is_user_logged_in()) return false`
- Checking user ID `wp_get_current_user()->ID`
- Checking by your role/permission system
- now that you have user ID, you do what you want with it
- use the `WP_REST_Request $request` parameter to handle GET or POST HTTP parameters.

So it could look like:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wc', '/test', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ]);
});

function my_awesome_func(WP_REST_Request $request)
{

    if (is_user_logged_in() && (int)wp_get_current_user()->ID === 123) {
        //your stuff only for legged in user 123
        return new WP_REST_Response('ok', 200);
    }

    return new WP_Error('unauthorized', __('You shall not pass'), [ 'status' => 401 ]); //can also use WP_REST_Response
}
```

It seems there may be [proper ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026264/woocommerce-rest-api-add-custom-routes) to add a Woocommerce REST API endpoint (couldn't find proper documentation about it...). But I tested this and it worked, at least to use the Woocommerce key/Secret authentication system, which I believe is applied under the `/wc/` endpoint.

Note: careful adding routes to the wc endpoints, as you may override an existing route endpoint. Eg: adding `/product/mytest` could conflict with an official Woocommerce route that handles `/product/[product_id]`.

Note 2: I first tested with a [custom WordPress REST API route](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), and passing Woocommerce key/secret to see if WordPress could see me correctly authenticated and identified. But it didn't work (WP uses [the core API auth system](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)). So I moved to the Woocommerce API endpoint.

Note 3: You could achieve the same using the Wordpress REST API with a custom route, and a "machine to machine" authentication plugins like Oauth, application password, JWT... like described on [WP REST API authentication documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).

Comment: That worked great! And you linked to an awesome alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but with reflection we can use WC auth logic to validate custom API routes.

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    /**
     * Register here your custom routes for your CRUD functions
     */
    register_rest_route( 'test/', 'wc-permissions', array(
        array(
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'            => 'read_check',
            'permission_callback' => 'do_wc_basic_auth_permission_check'
        ),
        array(
            'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
            'callback'            => 'write_check',
            'permission_callback' => 'do_wc_basic_auth_permission_check',
        ),
    ) );
} );

/**
 * Perform check via official WC REST auth class by reflecting method accessibility.
 * Uses official auth class, so it triggers all hooks as on normal 'wp-json/wc/v3/' routes
 *
 * @return bool
 * @throws ReflectionException
 */
function validate_request_has_valid_wc_api_keys(): bool {
    // WC not enabled, target reflection class is probably not registered
    if ( ! function_exists( 'WC' ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $method = new ReflectionMethod( 'WC_REST_Authentication', 'perform_basic_authentication' );
    $method->setAccessible( true );

    return $method->invoke( new WC_REST_Authentication ) !== false;
}

function write_check() {
    return 'can create new entry via POST';
}

function read_check() {

    return 'can get entry content via GET';
}
```

If you would like do add this authentication checks to other routes globally, f.e. core WP routes, you can use `add_filter('rest_dispatch_request', function ( $intendedResponse, $request, $route )` filter and try to match passed `$route` param with regex or some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my two cents in...

I was wondering if there's another way to add a new API endpoint which uses WooCommerce consumer key and secret authorization, avoiding possible collisions with WooCommerce `/wc/` endpoints, and not resorting to using reflection.

The answer is in the `is_request_to_rest_api` function included in the `WC_REST_Authentication` class. In order to use WooCommerce authentication method, the endpoint namespace of third-party plugins should start with `wc-`.

E.g.:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route(
    'wc-myprefix/v1',
    '/orders/(?P<order_id>\d+)/shipment-trackings',
    array(
      'methods'             => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
      'callback'            => 'get_shipment_trackings',
      'permission_callback' => 'check_permission',
    ),
  );
});

function get_shipment_trackings( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // return shipment trackings
}

function check_permission() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'read_private_shop_orders' ) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'woocommerce_rest_cannot_view',
            __( 'Sorry, you cannot list resources.', 'myprefix' ),
            array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() ) );
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please note the `wc-myprefix/v1` namespace of the new route (starting with `wc-`), and the use of the `current_user_can` function in the permission callback. It's the call to this function that triggers the actual authentication.

And if you're like me and don't really want anybody telling you how your endpoint namespace should be named, there's a handy filter (`woocommerce_rest_is_request_to_rest_api`) that you can use to implement your own logic to determine whether the call is to a rest API endpoint (i.e. check for your own particular endpoint namespace).